# Python compare rows and columns of a table

Tags: python

I am looking for an efficient way to compare rows and columns of a table against each other (>= gets 1, otherwise 0) and store the result.

Example:

```
           0.3642286    0.7945753    0.3527125 
0.3642286      1            1            0             
0.7945753      0            1            0
0.3527125      1            1            1
```

I have 21 tables with 480*480 rows and columns. What would be a proper way of generating and storing such a matrix?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Are you more interested in the data structure or the algorithm ?

Comment: I tried to do everything in files but I am not happy with it. I am interested in both data structure (a smarter way) and algorithm (for curiosity).

Comment: Usually people tend to help out more when you post code that you've done and ask a more specific question

Comment: It looks like you're comparing a row and column of identical values to each other -- so how does that apply to a 2D table?

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong term, I corrected it.

Comment: Possibly looking into numpy arrays and the `where` function would help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need is two loops.

```
def compare(first, second):
    result = []

    for x in first:
        result.append([])
        for y in second:
            result[-1].append(1 if x >= y else 0)

    result = [list(i) for i in zip(*result)]

    return result
```

Comment: I also did it with loops, I was just curios whether there is a better way.

Comment: Not that I know of. Like the other answer said, maybe NumPy has a better way. I don't think you'll need any optimization with 480*480 tables.

Comment: Thanks, I did not used numpy before but I will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider NumPy ([1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html)) if you are regularly handling large multi-dimensional arrays.